# Trust Boundary Violation - Veracode flaw

Tags: java, security, veracode

I'm getting trust boundary violation in the code that i'm testing. The code adds forms in session and it is getting flawed as trust boundary violation

```
Inside Struts Action class execute method
{
 EditForm editform = new EditForm ();
 All the values are set either from databse or from request params and then the form is   added to session as below

 **request.getSession(false).setAttribute("EDIT_FORM", editform );**
}
```

I'm getting violation on the code shown as bold.

How can i fix this? I'm not sure where to add the validation. It is a new form that is created inside Action class execute methods and the vaues are populated from request and db

Comment: The basic problem is that you're mixing trusted data (from the database) with untrusted data (from form data).  You should validate user input before mixing it in with trusted data so that the entire collection contains only trusted data.

Comment: You mean that i have to validate all the values that i'm using from request parameters inside execute method?

Comment: @kachan were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should try esapy library, try something like :

- ESAPI.getValidInput(...)

Before setting attribute. I've found this flaw asociate to Object type variable and that's the worst thing ever, because you cannot validate it as you can't know the type.

Comment: Then how are you able to go around validating the Object type variables? Do you any idea. I use the getValidInput() for String content.